# How do you say ‘sockdolager’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word ‘[sockdolager](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-sockdolager.html)’ appears neither in Benson, nor in Wells, nor in Vikivortaro, nor in Vikipedio, nor in ReVo, nor in Sonja. So, how should it be rendered in Esperanto?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it violates the following section of the "how to ask" page:

Make it relevant to others

We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander: What you cite is labeled as merely a ‘tip’. A tip is not a requirement. You can’t ‘violate’ a tip.

Comment: Now two people have +1ed my comment saying I was voting to close this question, but it's still only at one close vote. If you agree that it should be closed, remember to vote. Mike - yes it's just a tip, but given the reaction to your previous similar questions, I am hoping that you'll see that narrow questions about obscure words - with "link only" explanations - do not constitute quality questions and are not generally the sort of thing people want on this site.

Comment: @Torquemada: If you knew in advance exactly what you wanted to see, there would be no point in having the site in the first place.

Comment: This is a totally valid question. Please refrain from ”personal attacks” just because the asker – Mike Jones – has asked similar questions before. Without questions, this SE will die and soon become closed. If you can ask about how to say ”to afford” in Esperanto, you surely can ask about more obscure words as well. I’ve upvoted.

Comment: I have made no personal attacks. (Compare this to Mike Jonen's use of "Torquemada" to refer to me.) I have merely been direct. The fact is that this question "violates the tip" of making sure that questions are of general interest. It is not a personal attack to ask Mike Jones to use the feedback which has been given to him - that is, to avoid link-only answers and link-only questions, to provide more context in his questions about what he's trying to ask, and to make sure his questions are of broader interest.

Comment: @Tomaso Alexander – Ok, I agree that Mike Jones should refrain from namecalling. And maybe broaden his questions, although I still find this question just as ”valid” as a question about how to say *smoothie* in Esperanto, for example. :_)

Comment: There is something wrong with 'the scope defined in the help center' if such a question 'does not appear to be about Esperanto'.

Comment: A link is worth a thousand words: http://www.newyorker.com/cartoons/random/

Answer (score 1):

What about one of these

- **definitiva solvo**
- **definitiva respondo**

Cf. Merriam Webster’s [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sockdolager) of *sockdolager* in English.

The linked example phrase in your question could then be rendered like this:

> Esperanto is the sockdolager of the language barrier.
>
> **Esperanto estas la definitiva solvo de la lingva problemo.**

Comment: The original English is one word, and of low register. I'm holding out for the same in Esperanto, but I've up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus more on expressing ideas and not translating words. You've posted several questions of this form -- citing obscure English words and giving no clarification (other than nested links) of what idea you're trying to express.

Comment: I've down-voted. That's not an answer.

Comment: I agree – this is not an answer to the question (which is a valid question, even if you don’t like the question). I’ve down-voted, too.

Comment: Of course it's not an answer. I posted it to see how the community would react. So far, two people have voted it up. The question is valid in the sense that all questions are valid - but the fact that two people have voted this non-answer up suggests that the community agrees that questions are more appropriate for this site if they are complete (not using nested links) and of general interest. This is one of several questions the asker has posted with this format, and I believe the community has spoken with specific suggestions on how he can post better questions.

Comment: Community-related questions should be posted at Meta: https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com :-)

Comment: Also, 2 upvotes is not a lot considering the number of users…